# SQL case with sub query

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and getting out of my depth. This (below) works 'sort of' but not really. In that the sub-query works and the case works and it doesn't return an error message but I want to make the case statement outside the sub-query. I need to show 3 columns 'Yes or No', the 'year', and an 'average' number of yes' and no's per year. When I try to move the case statement as a column outside the sub query it doesn't recognise the 'title' or 'body' fields. What else do I need to do? I have tried making the case statement a sub-query and joining it, I have read through as many of the similar questions as I can and tried things but they all seem to be more complicated than my question.

```
SELECT year, ROUND(avg(view_count),2) AS Average_Number
  from
   (
      select extract(YEAR from creation_date) as year, count
           , CASE
             WHEN upper (title) like'%AGREE%' or upper (body)like '%AGREE%'
             THEN'YES'
             ELSE 'NO'
             END AS Statement
        from posts_questions
       where upper (title) like'%AGREE%'
          or upper (body)like '%AGREE%'
          or upper (title) like'%DISAGREE%' or upper (body)like '%DISAGREE%'
       group by count, creation_date, title, body
       order by year desc
   ) x
 group by year, Statement
 order by year
;
```

Comment: The columns won't be seen outside the derived table (subquery) unless they are in the `SELECT` list / result set of that subquery.  Add them appropriately to the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Please show the actual table definition with column names and types, plus some data and the expected result you want to generate, based on that data.  Add this detail to your question.

Comment: A clear explanation of what you want to accomplish, along with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adjusted your logic slightly due to 'AGREE' being a substring of 'DISAGREE'.

Some of your tests would have always found `'DISAGREE' LIKE '%AGREE%'` to be true, before noticing it is `LIKE '%DISAGREE%'`.

I've also shown that this can be done without the subquery, with your current requirement.

Note: Some databases might not handle using the derived column name directly in the `GROUP BY` clause.  So you might need to adjust that.  Tag your question with the specific database you are using.

Just the subquery for testing:

```
select extract(YEAR from creation_date) as year, count
     , CASE
       WHEN upper (title) like '%DISAGREE%'
         or upper (body)  like '%DISAGREE%'
       THEN 'NO'
       ELSE 'YES'
       END AS Statement
  from posts_questions
 where upper (title) like '%AGREE%'
    or upper (body)  like '%AGREE%'
    or upper (title) like '%DISAGREE%'
    or upper (body)  like '%DISAGREE%'
 group by count, creation_date, title, body
 order by year desc
;
```

The result of just the subquery (adjusted):

```
+------+-------+-----------+
| year | count | Statement |
+------+-------+-----------+
| 2021 |     2 | NO        |
| 2021 |     4 | YES       |
| 2021 |     3 | YES       |
| 2021 |     3 | NO        |
| 2020 |     2 | NO        |
+------+-------+-----------+
```

Solution without the subquery:

```
select extract(YEAR from creation_date) as year
     , AVG(count) AS avg_count
     , CASE
       WHEN upper (title) like '%DISAGREE%'
         or upper (body)  like '%DISAGREE%'
       THEN 'NO'
       ELSE 'YES'
       END AS Statement
  from posts_questions
 where upper (title) like '%AGREE%'
    or upper (body)  like '%AGREE%'
    or upper (title) like '%DISAGREE%'
    or upper (body)  like '%DISAGREE%'
 group by year, Statement
 order by year desc
;
```

Result:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| year | avg_count | Statement |
+------+-----------+-----------+
| 2021 |    2.5000 | NO        |
| 2021 |    3.5000 | YES       |
| 2020 |    2.0000 | NO        |
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Solution with the subquery.  Note: The `GROUP BY` in your subquery could be a problem (logically) if multiple entries in the table have the same tuple of values: `(count, creation_date, title, body)`

```
SELECT year
     , AVG(count) AS avg_count
     , CASE
       WHEN upper (title) like '%DISAGREE%'
         or upper (body)  like '%DISAGREE%'
       THEN 'NO'
       ELSE 'YES'
       END AS Statement
  FROM (
        select extract(YEAR from creation_date) as year, count
             , title
             , body
          from posts_questions
         where upper (title) like '%AGREE%'
            or upper (body)  like '%AGREE%'
            or upper (title) like '%DISAGREE%'
            or upper (body)  like '%DISAGREE%'
         group by count, creation_date, title, body
       ) x
 GROUP BY year, Statement
 ORDER BY year desc
;
```

Result:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| year | avg_count | Statement |
+------+-----------+-----------+
| 2021 |    2.5000 | NO        |
| 2021 |    3.5000 | YES       |
| 2020 |    2.0000 | NO        |
+------+-----------+-----------+
```